# Foxpro database Python automation error message

Tags: python, database, windows, automation, foxpro

I have a stocks database program written in Foxpro some of whose actions I am trying to automate in Python through the `pyautoit` package. I can successfully run the program and access its database by double clicking its exe file), but when I try to start the program via Python:

```
import autoit as au
au.run(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\...\stocks.exe')
```

I get the following message:

[image: Windows error message]

I am running Windows 7 professional, and the only 'Foxtools' file I can find in the program's folder is a `foxtools.fll` file.

Comment: Does the EXE run properly from a shortcut? If so, I wonder if this is a path issue.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor. Yes, it does. It works both from a shortcut and from the original program file. It seems like a path issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue. Just as @Tamar E. Granor said, it is a path issue. The `pyautoit` module provides an optional path parameter for the working directory which by default is set to be that of the Python file. Changing that WD to the Foxpro file directory resolves the conflict:

```
import autoit as au
au.run('C:\Program Files (x86)\...\stocks.exe',
       'C:\Program Files (x86)\...\[WD]')
```